# Act of Love vs. Act of Righteousness

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-balak, love

Devarim 23:6 - דברים כו פסוק ו

> וְלֹֽא־אָבָ֞ה הוי"ה אֱלֹהֶ֙יךָ֙ לִשְׁמֹ֣עַ אֶל־בִּלְעָ֔ם וַיַּהֲפֹךְ֩ הוי"ה אֱלֹקיךָ לְּךָ֛ אֶת־הַקְּלָלָ֖ה לִבְרָכָ֑ה כִּ֥י אֲהֵֽבְךָ֖ הוי"ה אֱלֹקיךָ׃
>   But the L-RD your God refused to heed Balaam; instead, the L-RD your
>   Gd turned the curse into a blessing for you, **for the L-RD your Gd
>   loves you**.

Gemara 7a -- גמרא ברכות דף ז עמוד א

> דאמר להו נביא לישראל עמי זכר נא מה יעץ בלק מלך מואב וגו׳ מאי למען דעת
>   **צדקות ה׳**
>
> And that is what the prophet said to Israel: “My nation, remember what
>   Balak king of Moab advised, and how Balaam, son of Beor, responded;
>   from Shittim to Gilgal, so that you may know **the righteous acts of
>   the L-rd**” (Micah 6:5). What is meant by the statement: “So that you
>   may know the righteous acts of the L-rd”?
>
> אמר רבי אלעזר אמר להם הקדוש ברוך הוא לישראל דעו **כמה צדקות עשיתי עמכם**
>   שלא כעסתי בימי בלעם הרשע שאלמלי כעסתי לא נשתייר משונאיהם של ישראל שריד
>   ופליט
>
> Rabbi Elazar said that the Holy One, Blessed be He, said to Israel:
>   Know how many **righteous acts I performed** on your behalf, that I did
>   not become angry during the days of Bilaam the wicked, for had I
>   become angry, there would have been no remnant or survivor remaining
>   among the enemies of Israel, [a euphemism for Israel itself]. Instead,
>   Gd restrained His anger and Bilaam’s curse went unfulfilled.

Question:

Why is it that the fact that Hashem turned the curse into a blessing considered an act of showing the love of Hashem toward Yisrael, and the fact that Hashem did not become angry during the days of Bilaam is considered a "righteous act" of Hashem?